# Codename One Picker text spinning after item is selected

Tags: codenameone, picker

I have a CN1 application that uses three pickers inside a container.

One of the pickers just contains small strings like "1x" , "2x" , etc.

Every time an item is selected on the running application, the selected text spins really fast, what looks kind of odd.

I have tried setting padding and margin to zero, and set SmoothScrolling to false.

```
picker.setSmoothScrolling(false);
```

All to no avail.

Is there ant solution to it?   Many thanks in advance ..

Here is the relevant part of the code:

```
    private final Picker pickerInterval = new Picker();   
    private final Picker pickerDayOrMonth = new Picker(); 
    private final Picker pickerFinal = new Picker();     

    String stringPickerInterval = "repetir a cada ..";
    pickerInterval.setType(Display.PICKER_TYPE_STRINGS);
    pickerInterval.setUIID("DatePickerDialog");
    pickerInterval.setStrings("1","2","3","4","5","6","6","8","9","10","11","12",stringPickerInterval);        
    pickerInterval.setSelectedString(stringPickerInterval);
    pickerInterval.addActionListener((e) -> {
        if (!pickerInterval.getSelectedString().equals(stringPickerInterval)) {
            pickerInterval.setUIID("DatePickerDialogSelected"); 
        } else {
            pickerInterval.setUIID("DatePickerDialog"); 
        }
    });

    String stringPickerDayOr = "dias ou semanas ou ...";
    pickerDayOrMonth.setType(Display.PICKER_TYPE_STRINGS);
    pickerDayOrMonth.setUIID("DatePickerDialog");
    pickerDayOrMonth.setStrings("Dia(s)", "Semana(s)", "Mes(es)","Ano(s)" , stringPickerDayOr);       
    pickerDayOrMonth.setSelectedString(stringPickerDayOr);
    pickerDayOrMonth.addActionListener((e) -> {
        if (!pickerDayOrMonth.getSelectedString().equals(stringPickerDayOr)) {
            pickerDayOrMonth.setUIID("DatePickerDialogSelected"); 
        } else {
            pickerDayOrMonth.setUIID("DatePickerDialog"); 
        }
    });        

    String stringPickerFinal = "freqüência das repetições ..";
    pickerFinal.setType(Display.PICKER_TYPE_STRINGS);
    pickerFinal.setUIID("DatePickerDialog");
    pickerFinal.setStrings("1 x","2 x","3 x","4 x","5 x","6 x","6 x","8 x","9 x","10 x","11 x","12 x" , stringPickerFinal);        
    pickerFinal.setSelectedString(stringPickerFinal);   
    pickerFinal.addActionListener((e) -> {
        if (!pickerFinal.getSelectedString().equals(stringPickerFinal)) {
            pickerFinal.setUIID("DatePickerDialogSelected"); 
        } else {
            pickerFinal.setUIID("DatePickerDialog"); 
        }
    });

    container = new Container(new GridLayout(1, 3));
    container.setUIID("ContainerPicker");
    container.add(pickerInterval).add(pickerDayOrMonth).add(pickerFinal);
```

Comment: Don't invoke `setSmoothScrolling(false)`. The picker looks completely different on the device. This is only in the simulator

Comment: In fact, the spinning effect only occurs on the installed device, not the simulator. It is an Android device.

Comment: I just have added some code to accompany the issue. As written before, the spinning effect only occurs on the installed Android device. Not in the simulator.

Comment: That's a native widget, if it misbehaves our options are limited as it maps directly to Android native functionality.